# How to position a component in the bottom center of a div without knowing its size in Css

Tags: css

which is the style to apply on a div to make component (button) centered in the botton without knowing the size of the remaining space that will take the div and the size of the button because this style will be generic.

I used this style but it didn't work for me:

```
<div location="buttonLayout" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:flex-end ;"></div>
```

The button is centered but not placed in the bottom of the remainig space of the parent div.

Comment: Try adding Vertical-align property and set it to bottom

Comment: Is button only child of that div?

Comment: Without knowing the size of the button, or the DIV?

Comment: 1) This button is only child of that div. 2) Without knowing the size of the remaining space to be taken in height. (of the DIV)

Comment: Your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/758/

Answer (score 4):

You could use absolute positioning to get button at the bottom middle:

```css
.parent {
  background: gold;  
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 48px; // Padding + button height
}

.parent button {
  background: grey;
  border: none;
  height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>Button any size</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `bottom: 0;` to the button.

If you have the following HTML:

```
<div id="flexItem" location="buttonLayout">
  <button id="bottomButton" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

You can use this CSS:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}

#flexItem{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content:center; 
  align-items:flex-end ;
}

#bottomButton{
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnx892n9/).

**Remember not to put inline CSS.**

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.mybutton {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

For this to work the parent container also has to have a position setting other than the default (static), for example `position: relative;`